# Which functions of a dll is called in OllyDBG

Tags: ollydbg, functions

I`m beginner in OllyDBG. In the debugging of an exe file, I found which dll is used (kernel32, ntdl, user32, etc). I want to get a list of all functions of each dll that are called.
How?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few ways to achieve this.

1. In OllyDbg search for all *Intermodular calls*. This would bring up a list of functions called from the main module. You can the set a logging breakpoint on all the functions. The disadvantage of this approach is that dynamically resolved function calls cannot not be intercepted.
   [image]
2. Search for *Name in all modules*. Next set logging breakpoints on all exported entries. Disadvantage of this approach is that there will be a lot of false positives such as when a function from *kernel32* calls into another function in *ntdll*, it will be logged too. To clear the false positives you can use a conditional logging breakpoint to check if the return address is within the ranges of the main module. 

   [image]
3. Use a dedicated tool for this purpose like [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), [SpyStudio](http://www.nektra.com/products/spystudio-api-monitor/) etc. If you use the SpyStudio, be sure to check out the [docs](http://whiteboard.nektra.com/trace-an-application-from-startup).